# Pure CSS Accordion - Reveal Content Issue

Tags: css, accordion

I have created a simple accordion using only html and css but there is one problem hopefully you can help me. The accordion is working properly but am using display:none to hide the content and then display:block to show it. I would like to have a smooth transition sliding down for .5s in order for the content to reveal  when the link is pressed, and when the user press another link i would like to slideup the active content and slidedown the content that is active.

Thanks

HTML Code:

```
<section id="accordion">
   <section id="accordion-title-1">
       <a href="#accordion-title-1">
           <h2>Videos</h2>
       </a>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis repellat obcaecati fugiat voluptatibus doloremque provident nihil, facilis harum quos excepturi officia assumenda odit, dolorem voluptates quidem molestiae velit, nostrum eligendi.</p>
   </section>
   <section id="accordion-title-2">
       <a href="#accordion-title-2">
           <h2>Videos</h2>
       </a>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis repellat obcaecati fugiat voluptatibus doloremque provident nihil, facilis harum quos excepturi officia assumenda odit, dolorem voluptates quidem molestiae velit, nostrum eligendi.</p>
   </section>
   <section id="accordion-title-3">
       <a href="#accordion-title-3">
           <h2>Videos</h2>
       </a>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis repellat obcaecati fugiat voluptatibus doloremque provident nihil, facilis harum quos excepturi officia assumenda odit, dolorem voluptates quidem molestiae velit, nostrum eligendi.</p>
   </section>
</section>
```

CSS Code:

```
* {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#accordion {
    margin-top:100px;
    padding:20px;
    background:#2e6572;
}

#c-accordion section {
 line-height: 1.6em;   
}


#accordion section a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

#accordion #accordion-title-2 a, #accordion #accordion-title-3 a {
    margin-top:20px;
}

#accordion section p {
    color:#bebebe;
    margin-top:20px;
    display: none;
}

#accordion section:target  p {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You cannot have animation on `display` property. However you can play with the `height` and `min-height` property. I have something in mind and will post it in some time

Comment: I would suggest using a transition with max-height.

Comment: I have tried with height but i didn't find the solution maybe you can help

Comment: I'd recommend you try a solution with JavaScript so you don't have to rely on the content height and magic numbers set in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting the changes to the css

```
#accordion section p {
    color:#bebebe;
    margin-top:20px;
    max-height:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
}

#accordion section:target  p {
    max-height:100px;
    overflow:none;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

Demo : http://jsbin.com/rivayagehe/edit?html,css,output

It's a bit rough and may need some polishing